# How to make a Template page to show the information of different things Shop and Product page?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization, templates

Is there a way to make a page with multiple items (Like a Shop or products page) and a Single information page / Details page? I want to make a Custom template of a Single Details page that will open the information of different items.

Comment: I edited out the request for a plugin recommendation as it would have forced me to close your question. You will need to be more specific though, including mentioning any plugins you're already using. If you're just asking how do I create a shop with a product listing though, then there are already multiple hugely popular plugins that are very difficult to miss, a quick google search for "wordpress ecommerce plugin" or something similar will show them, likewise "shop" on wp.org plugin search or in your WP admin page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/shop/

Comment: No, I am just referencing the shop plugin. I don't want to make a shop-like structure I have some items (Like houses and lands) and I want to show their details on one page. I don't want to create specific pages for each item. I don't want any cart or list etc.

Comment: You’re describing custom post types.

Comment: The answer is YES.  There are ways to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie was right, the thing I wanted was custom post types.
Thanks a lot, bro.